# Rescaling function for probability of $k$ adjacent ones in a binary string

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Call $\xi$ a random variable taking values in $\{0, 1\}^{\{0, 1, 2, \ldots, n\}}$, where each character of the string has vaalue $1$ with probability $p$ and $0$ with probability $1-p$ independently. Denote by $P(k)$ the probability that the string contains at least $k$ adjacent ones. Consider a function $f(n) : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. What should be the dependence of $f(n)$ on $n$ in order the probability $P(\frac{k}{f(n)})$ to converge to a non-degenerate density as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: "Define $P(\frac{k}{f(n)})$" ... what? That does not define anything I can understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to reformulate the question:

> Consider a sequence $(X_k)$ i.i.d. with $P(X_1=1)=p$. Give some asymptotics of $L_n$ the length of the maximal run of ones before time $n$ when $n\to\infty$.

Thus $L_n\geqslant\ell$ if there exists $\ell$ consecutive ones in the sequence $(X_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}$.
The asymptotics of $(L_n)$ are that 
$$
L_n/\log n\to-\log p,
$$ 
in probability. Furthermore, the normalized version of $L_n$, defined as
$$
M_n=L_n+\log p\cdot\log n,
$$ 
converges in distribution to a random variable $M$ with a double exponential distribution, that is, for every real number $x$,
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}P(M_n\leqslant x)=P(M\leqslant x)=\mathrm e^{-(1-p)p^x}.
$$
In other words, $M$ has the density $f_M$ defined by
$$
f_M(x)=-(1-p)\log p\cdot\mathrm e^{x\log(1-p)-(1-p)\mathrm e^{x\log p}}.
$$
Is this what you are after?

Comment: Yes I was interested in this. What is the strategy to prove the behaviour of $P(M \leq x)$?

Comment: To compute the generating function of the time $T_n$ when the first run of length $n$ is completed, then to use the duality relation $[T_n\leqslant k]=[L_k\geqslant n]$.